# How to avoid potential memory leak at jackson.databind?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jackson

How can I solve a memory leak at `jackson.databind`? My sample program uses jackson to serialize objects like this:

```
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() 
    .enableDefaultTyping()     
    .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING) 
    .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL) 
    .disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); 

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msg);
```

This results are after a few minutes:

[image]

Comment: hi, what profiler did you use to see the objects in memory like that ? tks